# How could I build a decent half-elf illusionist inquisitor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Inspired by a [Wayfinder](http://cdn.paizo.com/image/product/catalog/PZOPDFWAY/PZOPDFWAY013E.jpg) drawing made by [Dollicon](http://dollicon.tumblr.com/), I introduced an half-elf illusionist inquisitor NPC to my party. I quite like her and I plan to play her as character next time (GM role is going to switch).

[image: wayfinder_inquisitor2_by_dollicon]

I started the build but I struggle a bit. Can you help me add missing pieces? I imagine her as a high wisdom spontaneous caster character controlling the battlefield, being a face and spy when needed. I don't care about damage (we already have some good dps).

We are level 8 and we don't plan to increase this level a lot. Maybe reaching slowly 10 or 12. We quite like the balance around 8.

I think I will pick 2 inquisitor levels to get monster lore, cunning initiative and detect alignment. I am not sure what Domain or Inquisition should I pick for my concept.

- Conversion Inquisition (for Charm of Wisdom)
- Clandestine Inquisition (for Conversion Inquisition)
- Trickery Domain (for Copycat)
- Deception Subdomain (for Sudden Shift)
- ???

Therefore, I didn't find a good illusion-minded archetype for inquisitor. Did I miss something?

To be able to go full spontaneous wisdom-based caster, I chose to be a [Celestial](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/celestial-bloodline/) [Wildblooded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/) [Empyreal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/mutated-bloodlines-paizo/empyreal) Sorcerer. Since I plan a high wisdom and empyreal is not really illusion useful, I think I can afford to be crossblooded (and I like the idea). I am not sure which one to choose... Umbral, fey, arcana and rakshasa seem nice. Any input is welcome!

I think she will be a [Tattooed Sorcereress](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/tattooed-sorcerer) with a [Scorpion, Greensting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/scorpion/scorpion-greensting) (sweet +4 init).

I am looking to choose four levels of sorcerer and maybe more. Veiled Illusionist is in theme, but I am not sure if it is worth it for my build.

1. Inquisition
2. Inquisition
3. Sorcerer
4. Sorcerer
5. Sorcerer
6. Sorcerer
7. ???
8. ???

### Ability scores

20 points buy with in my mind: WIS > DEX > CON / CHA/ INT > FOR

- FOR 7 (-2)
- DEX 14 (2)
- CON 12 (1)
- INT 10 (0)
- WIS 18 (4)
- CHA 10 (1)

With half-elf bonus, headband and 4th+8th, Wisdom could reach 24 (7) and with a belt DEX 16 (3). With this output we need to be able to use Wisdom instead of CHA for skills. Another idea would be:

- FOR 7 (-2)
- DEX 14 (2)
- CON 12 (1)
- INT 12 (1)
- WIS 16 (3)
- CHA 14 (2)

With half-elf bonus, headband and 4th+8th, Wisdom could reach 22 (6) and with a belt DEX 16 (3). With this output we are a bit more MAD.

### Race

The vanilla half-elf is good. Multidisciplined and Sociable are useful. If I pick Multidisciplined, I will drop Magical Knack.

### Traits & Drawbacks

- Magicak Knack (for the sorcerer)
- Adopted(Trickster)
- a +2 bonus to Initiative (Reactionary, elven reflex, etc.)

In another hand, Iron Will can be a nice counter to the drawback of Crossblooded.

### Drawbacks

I hesitate between [Empty Mask](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/drawbacks/empty-mask/) and [Paranoid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/drawbacks/paranoid/). Both are flavorful.

### Feats

1. Spell Focus in Illusion
2. Silent Spell?
3. Still Spell?
4. ???

Is there a way to get Effortless Trickery (gnome) as a half-elf (something like the adopted trait)? As a half-elf, maybe there is a way to get [Racial Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/racial-heritage), but I am not sure it is worth it. Improved Initiative is still nice to have, but I think I am already fast enough.

### Skills

// coming

### Spells

Ok so we are in the sweet illusion-supported manipulation business. Lets see our stock.

#### Inquisitor (2 levels)

- Known: 5 level 0 | 3 level 1
- Per day: at will | 2+2 (thank you WIS)

Spells known

level 0:

- [Guidance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guidance)
- [Brand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/brand)
- [Sift](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sift)
- [Resistance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resistance)
- [Acid Splash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-splash) (for sabotage and to mark)

level 1:

- [Command](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/command)

#### Sorcerer (4 levels)

- Known: 6-1 level 0 | 3-1 level 1 | 1-1 (0?) level 2 (crossblooded hurt)
- Per day: at will | 6+2 | 3+2 (thank you WIS)

If we lost the possibility to cast 2th level spell, we cannot be Veiled Illusionist at 7th level. What could be a counter to this crossblooded drawback?

Spells known

level 0:

- [Ghost Sound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghost-sound/)
- [Prestidigitation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation/)
- [Mage Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-hand/)
- [Detect Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic)
- [Message](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/message)? [Touch of Fatigue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-fatigue)?

level 1:

- [Silent Image](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/silentImage.html#silent-image)
- [Color Spray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/color-spray)
- [Disguise self](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/disguiseSelf.html#disguise-self) (only if I don't pick the hat)

### Equipments (33k gp)

- Headband of Inspired Wisdom +2 (4k)
- Belt of Incredible Dexterity +2 (4k)
- Circlet of Persuasion (4,5k) or Hat of Disguise (1,8k)?
- Cloak of Resistance +? (?k)
- [Gloves of Reconnaissance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-reconnaissance)? (2k)
- metamagic rods?
- ???

I am not sure if I need a havresac. A smaller bag should be enough. I am not sure about using a weapon ; maybe a crossbow and a dagger. If I pick a weapon with the idea of using it, Guided may worth it.

### Note

We allow all Paizo content. We dont use Psychic magic. We try to avoid min-maxing, but we all optimized a bit. Flavor and fluff first though :)

Comment: What are you trying to maximize out of this build? Illusion spell DC? Spells per day? Non-combat utility (if so, what environment(s) do you expect to be in)?

Comment: @Ifusaso I want to maximize out my illusion power (higher DC, more spells, etc.). I want to be useful during the combat (but not leading it ) and outside of it. Environments I expect to be are cities and countryside right now, but as a Inquisitor (as occupation) we can be anywhere. I dont know what the next GM will do.

Comment: There's a lot here.  I could address a bunch of stuff in an answer, but it wouldn't be addressing all the stuff, just the stuff I felt like responding to with the understanding it seems like it handles the other stuff okay, too.  That makes me think this is much too broad, since the inclination is not to produce a complete answer but just a hugely large one. This is probably a better fit for a forum.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I understand your point. I will check again the rpg's FAQ. On Codereview.SE.com, most of  question are large and most answers complete each other. Any answer, even covering a small part of the build, can be useful for me or for anyone looking for a similar build. I will take all insight :)